# Result from API Post request not showing in view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I was wondering if anyone could make a suggestion as to why the results of the API post request are not showing in my view.

```
      if (token != null)
        {
            client.SetBearerToken(token.AccessToken);
            //ResultModel resultModel = new ResultModel();
            Result result = new Result();
            
            var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(address, bodyJson, null);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
               string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                //resultModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultModel>(apiResponse);
                result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(apiResponse);
            }
            return View(result);
        }
        return View();
```

I am struggling to figure out why the results aren't being shown, I used the PASTE special Paste JSON as classes and have deleted the ones I dont want to display.

I have attempted to use a for each to loop the results as there is 17 results in the display.

```
public class Result
{
    public class Rootobject
    {
        public string SearchGuid { get; set; }
        public Button[] Buttons { get; set; }
        public string CaseRef { get; set; }

    }

    public class Button
    {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Result class not have property... the result is always void....

Answer (score 0):

you have to fix the classes

```
public class Result
{
    public Rootobject Rootobject {get; set;}
    public Button Button {get; set;}
 
}
 public class Rootobject
    {
        public string SearchGuid { get; set; }
        public Button[] Buttons { get; set; }
        public string CaseRef { get; set; }

    }
   public class Button
    {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    }
```